# Prevent ContentPresentor while scaled to resize all objects in it's content

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior, contentpresenter

Hey guys,
I have a ContentPresenter which contains Image inside of it and a few Ellipses (points).
There's a Zoom behavior on the ContentPresenter and it scales all the objects inside of it.
Does anyone have an idea how to stop the scaling of the Ellipses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't thin it would be possible to do it automatically, you probably need to find some strategy to "unscale" the ellipses. I did something similar, but about line thickness, on this sample: http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/03/21/ACADFriendlyWPFZoomBehavior.aspx and I think you can grab the idea.